# Connecting postgresql with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I know this might be really a simple question but I don't know the solution. What is happening here when I try to connect to postgresql? I am self learner in this field of database and programming so please be gentle with me.
When I try following code:

```
import sqlalchemy
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql:///tutorial.db')
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "", line 1, in 
>       db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql:///tutorial.db')
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.7.5dev-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine__init__.py", line 327, in create_engine
>       return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.7.5dev-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 64, in create
>       dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.7.5dev-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py", line 289, in dbapi
>       psycopg = **import**('psycopg2')
>   ImportError: No module named psycopg2

Do I need to install psycopg2 separately? What is the correct connection string for postgresql?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes, psycopg2 are basically the Python drivers for PostgreSQL that need to be installed separately.

A list of valid connection strings can be found here, yours is a bit off (you need to the username, the password and hostname as specified in the link below):

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#postgresql

Comment: I'm honestly baffled that this is not a dependency of SQLAlchemy. If you are going to wrap functionality of another package with yours, you should support it and not require a separate installation.

Comment: @StevenWade not really, you don't usually want to install dependencies for *all* database systems when you are going to use possibly only one. That's why dependencies in this kind of packages are optional, and not enforced.

Answer (score 120):

You would need to `pip install SQLAlchemy` and `pip install psycopg2`.
An example of a SQLAlchemy connection string that uses psycopg2:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@hostname/database_name')
```

You could also connect to your database using the psycopg2 driver exclusively:

```
import psycopg2
conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='my_database' user='postgres' password='secret'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
```

However, using the psycopg2 driver to connect does not take advantage of SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I have another question about `postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@...`, why someone articles say only use `postgresql://user:password@...`, what's the difference?

Comment: According to this comment it is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946916/7775043

Comment: @TonyChou see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html: "The PostgreSQL dialect uses psycopg2 as the default DBAPI", so there is no difference. " DBAPI is a 'low level' API which is typically the lowest level system used in a Python application to talk to a database."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to install psycopg2 separately, if you're using linux you can simply enter the following line to the terminal: `$pip install psycopg2` if this doesn't work try using sudo: `$sudo pip install psycopg2`

Comment: Requires pg_config, which may not be present for everyone. I'm working in Docker, and it was not in my case.