# How do I connect to Postgresql server from Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, postgresql-9.1, raspberry-pi

My final goal is to setup a server on my raspberry pi which can connect to a local postgresql server.
Im a bit familiar with postgres therefore I installed it on my raspberry pi immediately.
however, I dont see any reasonable solution on how to connect to it from within python.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you look at something like this? http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a SQL Alchemy post which can help

[Connecting postgresql with sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353822/connecting-postgresql-with-sqlalchemy)

you will need to install pyscopg2

Comment: Or just use `psycopg2` directly if you don't want the abstraction layer.