# What is the difference between postgres and postgresql_psycopg2 as a database engine for django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I have worked with python for a while, but never django. I am taking over a project that a different employee made before leaving our company. I am wondering if there is a difference between the option postgresql and postgresql_psycopg2 as a database driver for django.

In some articles and the docs about how to set up a django project I have seen just postgresql and in [others](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) I have seen the postgresql_psycopg2. I couldn't find anything in the docs ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases)  or [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#engine)) that mentioned psycopg2, so is this just the old way of writing the option?

Is one just an alias for the other or are they actually different enignes? I also couldn't find any other SO questions on this.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',# here I also saw postgres_psycopg2
    'NAME': 'premqcsite',
    'USER': 'django_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'Encepta_123',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's the same. `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` used in django <1.8 and it was renamed in django 1.9 to `django.db.backends.postgresql`.
From docs:

> Changed in Django 1.9:
>
> The django.db.backends.postgresql backend is named
>   django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 in older releases. For
>   backwards compatibility, the old name still works in newer versions.

Comment: Is it still required to install pycopg_2 with pip or is it now included in Django?

Comment: @Tanckom I also had the same question and found out it's not included. You have to install it before running **migrate** command