# What is the use of "psycopg2" in Django while connecting to PostgreSQL

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

What is the use of the `psycopg2` PostgreSQL database adapter;

or what is the difference between using ***postgresql*** vs ***postgresql_psycopg2*** while establishing connection in the `settings.py` file in a Django project?

Because either one works fine for me.

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'

'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.9/):

> The PostgreSQL backend (django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2) is
>   also available as django.db.backends.postgresql. The old name will
>   continue to be available for backwards compatibility.

Actually, this question is already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946856/what-is-the-difference-between-postgres-and-postgresql-psycopg2-as-a-database-en).