# Is it possible to use Windows DSN to connect to postgresql via sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a connection to PostgreSQL created in the Windows ODBC Data Source. I'm using pyodbc to connect to the PostgreSQL database like this:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=PostgreSQL35W')
```

I'm now using SQLAlchemy and would like to connect to the database using a Windows DSN like I do with pyodbc. Is this possible? I need to use the Windows DSN.

Comment: Is this [Connecting postgresql with sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9353822/6194097) question help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting postgresql with sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353822/connecting-postgresql-with-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Based on your results I don't think SQLAlchemy supports using pyodbc to connect to PostgreSQL which means it won't support ODBC DSNs.

Comment: Also, please delete the two answers you posted that were in response to my answer. The feedback was welcome and they've served their purpose. Unfortunately this site does not have a good way to provide feedback to answers other than through comments which are limited. Stack Overflow has strict rules that answers should exclusively be answers and not replies.