# How do you get the url of a postgresql database you made in pgadmin?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pgadmin

so i created a postgresql database and i want to link it to my python code using sqlalchemy but since i made the database in pgadmin i dont know what to mention as the url of the database in the code.
thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to look for the connection IP and the credentials you used to create the database. These may or may not be in the screenshot you have; how can we know? (don't share a an IP screenshot of a non-local IP). You need to look at documentation, not ask here

Answer (score 15):

If you created your database using the defaults, you can probably login to the server using psql (SQL Shell).

Try to connect to the database you created and if you are able to connect to the database try `\conninfo`.

If it's on your own machine the output will be quite standard host will be `localhost`, ip will be `127.0.0.1` and port will be the default port of `5432`.

[image: Screenshot of a psql shell with an example of the command conninfo]

Once you make sure of these things you should try to connect to the database using the following code from this [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42587012/3851798).

Please make sure you have both SQLAlchemy and psycopg2 installed before you try to connect. Then try this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@hostname/database_name')
```

Or may be find a good tutorial on SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 9):

Go back into pgAdmin, click on the node for your server and then check the values under "Connection" in the "Properties" page:

[image: pgAdmin]

According to [the SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2) the corresponding connection URL for those values would be

```python
connection_url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@localhost:5432/db_name'
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]
With the upper picture setting. I use following pattern

```
postgresql://postgres:[MY_PASSWORD]@localhost:5432/[DATABASE_NAME]


postgresql://[YOUR_USERNAME]:[YOUR_PASSWORD]@[YOUR_HOST_NAME]:[YOUR_PORT]/[DATABASE_NAME]
```

Comment: I do i reach this screen ?

Comment: Expand servers > Right click on psql versions > select properties